# Google login without Google+ profile

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to create the possibility for Google users to login with their account and use my Android app. Important aspect is that we don't want our users to be forced to create a Google+ profile for their account. According to the documentation I can use the GoogleApiClient to do this.
According to this page: https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable asking for only the users basic profile will not prompt users to create a Google+ profile. My experience is that it does.

I use the following code to initiate my googleApiClient:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(listener)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(listener)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .addScope(new Scope("email"))
                .build();
```

I would expect that the user can login with a normal account, but they receive the request to create a Google+ profile and can't login without it.

Is there any way to use the googleApiClient to let users login with a normal Google account (without Google+ profile)? Or should I abandon the client and do a Google login another way?